# What are the CONT and FLT modes of the 737 start switches?

Tags: boeing-737, engine

I pilot the PMDG 737 in my simulator and I know that before takeoff and before landing, the start switches must be set to CONT mode and at high altitudes in FLT mode. But what exactly are CONT and FLT mode? What they do ?

Comment: You really shouldn't accept an answer quite _that_ quickly - it's generally recommended to wait a couple days for Stackers in other time zones to have a chance to respond.

Comment: Oh ok. This is a craze that I have come from other platforms, sorry.

Comment: No worries.  :-)  And now you know!

Comment: If an answer is (in the opinion of the OP) complete, clear, and it answers the question, then why shouldn't it be accepted? Could you please provide a link/clarification as to "it's generally recommended"? Some answers (ideally all, in fact) are entirely fact-based. If the question is, say, "What's the ceiling of X model" and there is an answer, with sources, what's the point of waiting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The 737 has two separate engine-igniter systems (each of which has igniters on both engines).](http://www.b737.org.uk/powerplant.htm#Ignition)  Each engine has four possible igniter modes (except for earlier-model Originals, which have five) - in clockwise order 'round the knob, they're GND, OFF, CONT (or, for early Originals, L IGN and R IGN), and FLT.

- CONT mode turns *one* of the igniter systems on (*which* igniter system is used depends on the position of a separate switch), and is used for takeoff and landing.

  - GND mode on an Original or Classic, or on an NG that's on the ground, also uses a single igniter system, and is used for ground-starting the engines.
- FLT mode turns *both* igniter systems on, the better to help keep the engines operating under adverse conditions, or maximise the chance of a successful midair relight.  In the real world, FLT mode is used only in conditions posing a significant risk of engine flameout (for instance, extreme turbulence or very heavy rain), or if a flameout *has already occurred* and one or both engines need to be restarted in flight - *not* for high-altitude cruise flight in general.

  - On an NG, GND mode is another option for inflight restarts, in which case it uses both igniters (unlike how it operates for ground starts).
- Your simulator might be confusing FLT mode with OFF mode (*neither* igniter system operating), which is the setting normally used in flight (as combustion in a gas-turbine engine is generally self-sustaining unless the engine, or its fuel or air supply, is severely abused).

Additionally, on an NG, the EECs can automatically switch both igniter systems on (if an engine flames out) or off (if bad things happen during ground-starting), no matter what the position of the ignition knobs.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, please either create a new question, or edit the question to cover all modes. Diverging discussion does not work well on this site as it orders posts by votes, not time.